FMCW radar does not give range
I have designed a 2.4 GHz FMCW radar from the components presented below:
VCO: CVCO55CC-2400-2569
LNA: ADL5545ARKZ-R7
Coupler: D17W+
Mixer: ADE-30+
Block diagram of the system:

If i only supply a DC voltage to the tune pin of the VCO, the doppler shift can be observed when a moving target is infront of the antennas. But when i try to get range information by using a sawtooth chirp the IF output FFT shows constant peaks which are very close to the frequency of the chirp signal. For instance, using a chirp with a frequency of 1.3 kHz ~(0.6 - 3.0V) i get a peak at roughly 2 kHz. This beat frequency does not depend on any objects infront of the antennas. Why does this happen? i have tried with different chirp frequencies (1-30 kHz) and the same behavior can be observed but at different frequencies related to the chirp frequency.
My guess is that there are some reflections in the PCB which causes this "chirp leaked". Might be becuse of bad soldering, FR4 board, impedance missmatches...
Below is the PCB:

This is the oscilloscope output from the IF (Yellow), Chirp (Purple)


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
